# Signs of difference matrices (sum of submatrices)

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices

Given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, are there any results related to its difference array
$$A^* \triangleq \left[sign(a_{i,j} + a_{r, s} - a_{r, j} - a_{i, s})\right]_{i<r, j<s}?$$

Or equivalently, given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, are there any results related to 
$$\hat{A} \triangleq \left[sign\left(\sum_{x=i}^r \sum_{y=j}^s a_{x, y} \right)\right]_{i\le r, j\le s}?$$
Here, $sign: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \{+, -, 0\}$ is the sign function.

Comment: What kind(s) of results are you hoping for?

Comment: Anything is useful to me since I don't even know a name for this. I am trying to characterize this 4-dimensional pattern.